# How to access wordpress running on a docker container?

Tags: wordpress, apache, docker, containers

There is simply an ubuntu server with docker installed. Pulling wordpress docker image using

```
`$ docker pull wordpress`.
```

Then running the container using

```
$ docker run --name my-wp -p 8080 -h 192.168.1.11 -d wordpress
```

Checking the logs:

```
$ docker logs my-wp
WordPress not found in /var/www/html - copying now...
Complete! WordPress has been successfully copied to /var/www/html
[Mon Mar 30 10:42:10.499346 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1] AH00163: Apache/2.4.38 
(Debian) PHP/7.3.16 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Mar 30 10:42:10.499390 2020] [core:notice] [pid 1] AH00094: Command line: 'apache2 -D 
FOREGROUND'
```

Checking running container and port number:

```
$ docker ps 
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                             NAMES
9a06a4bb7ce5        wordpress           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   22 minutes ago      Up 22 minutes       80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32769->8080/tcp   my-wp
```

Now I tried to access wordpress using ip 192.168.1.11:8080 and 192.168.1.11:32769 and 127.0.0.1:8080 and 127.0.0.1:32769. None could open the wordpress page.
Note that I already have a webserver running on port 80 on my host OS.

Any ideas on how to access wordpress web page?

Comment: If you haven't modified the Wordpress configuration at all, it looks like it's still listening on port 80 (the default HTTP port) inside the container.  This is a separate network namespace from your host system so it won't conflict.  Try changing `-p 8080` to `-p 80`; you can also pick the remapped port yourself `-p 8080:80`.

Comment: Thank you David. It was all a matter of remapping. I remapped the port 80 of the container to port 8080 in my host. All is working fine now. This is the working command: `$ docker run --name my-wp -p 8080:80 -d wordpress`. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to David Maze, whose comment helped to realise that port remapping is necessary. With the following command, I map port 80 of the container to port 8080 of the host, and now wordpress is accessible.

```
$ docker run --name my-wp -p 8080:80 -d wordpress
```